# Unable to modify table in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of the tables of my database doesn't have a PK and i want to make one of its columns to the PK. It has only two columns and the one i want to be the PK doesn't have the check mark in "Allow Nulls" so it shouldn't have any null data.
But when i attempt to do it i have this error

> 'PassedCourses' table
>   - Unable to modify table.   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 
>   'courseID', table 'HumanResources.dbo.Tmp_PassedCourses'; column does
>   not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

I use Microsoft SQL Server

```
USE [HumanResources]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PassedCourses]    Script Date: 3/4/2019 
3:57:47 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PassedCourses](
[employeeID] [float] NULL,
[courseID] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is the create script(I didn't make this database at first place)

I need to have a PK to add it in my WebApp but i can't add a new column as the PK because it has almost 11000 rows

I changed the data type to int.

Comment: Is there a reason you tagged MySQL as well? Also, you should really provide proper `CREATE` statements for your tables so we know exactly what you have.

Comment: The error message is clear. You tried to alter the table to setup column `CourseID` as primary key, but there are rows in the table with `NULL` in that column. All you need to do is make sure every row has an unique value in that column before you alter your table

Comment: @DavidG Sorry mate it's my first time asking questions i thought maybe people who worked with MySQL can help me too. I'll consider it in my next questions thanks.

Comment: @GuidoG It has almost 11000 rows :D

Comment: You should fix this question as well. That's why the [edit] button exists.

Comment: That is unfortunate that is has 11000 rows, still the column will need unique values before you can make it the primary key

Comment: Now that I can see the table schema, are you sure you want to make the column `CourseID` a primary key ? It will cause that every course in this table can have only one employee. Is that really what you want ?

Comment: @GuidoG I need a PK to add this table into my WebApp and i can't add a new column as a PK

Comment: Using `FLOAT` for what are (I assume) integer values is an accident waiting to happen. It can represent every `INT` value exactly, so that's OK, but it can also store many more inappropriate values, like `1.5`. Consider starting over with a new table with proper column types and a proper PK (possibly based on an `IDENTITY`, or else by having both columns as the PK) and then use an `INSERT` statement or the data import/export wizard to copy the data of the existing table to the new one. You can drop the current table and rename the new table to match the old one afterwards.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yeah i changed the data type into int. So you say i create another table (With proper columns and of course the PK) and transfer the data?

Comment: Creating a new table and copying data is more hassle-free than massaging an existing one, especially when things like changing column types are involved (which involves a rewrite of the table in the background anyway) or changing the `IDENTITY` property (which isn't even possible and requires a new column). With a small table like this one (11 000 rows is nothing to SQL Server) copying data is a lot simpler than modifying the original table. (Of course, this can swing the other way if things like foreign keys or triggers are involved.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert That's absolutely true thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Please set your Identity to 1 (Go to Column properties(PK Column) => Identity Specification =>Is identity = 1)
And you will not update PK Column Value.

Comment: I changed it to Yes, Identity Increment =1 and Identity Seed =1 (Data type was float i changed it to int and all of them changed automatically) but i still have this error.